# The order by clause returns wrong results in sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, rownum

I have the following query which is giving wrong result. I want to sort the PROCESS_START_DATE in a descending manner so that i will always get the latest PROCESS_START_DATE in my query. I ran the above query in oracle but its showing incorrect output. I want the latest PROCESS_CREATION_DATE in the descending order. For that i have written the query which is given in question. Its running absolutely fine when i remove the condition PROCESS_MONITOR.NAME = 'WORKFLOWINENGINE1'. But when i used this condition my query fails to generate the right output. I am not getting the latest PROCESS_CREATION_DATE

```
select * from(
select PROCESS_START_DATE
from PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC JOIN PROCESS_MONITOR ON PROCESS_MONITOR.ID=PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC.PROCESS_MONITOR_ID where PROCESS_MONITOR.NAME = 'WORKFLOWINENGINE1'
order by PROCESS_START_DATE desc)
where ROWNUM <= 1000
```

When i ran the below query i am getting the right result. But only when i used join condition then i am not getting the expected output.

```
select * from 
(select PROCESS_START_DATE
    from PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC
    order by PROCESS_START_DATE desc)
    where ROWNUM <=10
```

Comment: Two questions that would help us help you: What output did you expect? What output did you get?

Comment: the PROCESS_START_DATE i am return is wrong. Its showing the old PROCESS_START_DATE not the new one which i am expecting with this query as i sort it asc.

Comment: I believe you need to use the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function instead of the ROWNUM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `ORDER BY` clause is applied to a subquery, not the query itself, the order is lost for the outer query. You need two `ORDER BY` clauses there

- The inner `ORDER BY` is needed to pick correct rows with `ROWNUM`
- The outer `ORDER BY` is needed to ensure that the query results come in the correct order.

Here is the query that should work:

```
select * from(
    select PROCESS_START_DATE
    from PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC
    JOIN PROCESS_MONITOR ON PROCESS_MONITOR.ID=PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC.PROCESS_MONITOR_ID
    where PROCESS_MONITOR.NAME = 'WORKFLOWINENGINE1'
    order by PROCESS_START_DATE desc
) inner
where ROWNUM <= 1000
order by inner.PROCESS_START_DATE desc
```

Comment: hello i tried the above query but still its showing wrong PROCESS_START_DATE

Comment: Can you show us a) what you were expecting to see and b) what you actually saw, and explain what the difference is, please?

Comment: Hello but its still not running :(

Comment: Please check the update question where i have mentioned that the other query is running ..

Comment: @ajay You mentioned that you do not get the expected output when you use join, but you did not explain what is the difference between the output that you get and the output that you expected to get. Does the inner query produce the correct dates? Does it give you dates that do not belong to the expected set? Do you get duplicate dates? Please explain.

Comment: I want the latest PROCESS_CREATION_DATE in the descending order. For that i have written the query which is given in question. Its running absolutely fine when i remove the condition PROCESS_MONITOR.NAME = 'WORKFLOWINENGINE1'. But when i used this condition my query fails to generate the right output. I am not getting the latest PROCESS_CREATION_DATE

Comment: @ajay You should get the latest `PROCESS_CREATION_DATE` for the process with `PROCESS_MONITOR.NAME = 'WORKFLOWINENGINE1'` when you add the condition. Is it not the behavior that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

See here for methods of getting the correct result set for top-n. Also note the "What not to do" section which is exactly what you did.

http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries.php#mistake